# Can Facebook Chat Plugin be used in a React Native App?

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-messenger, facebook-chat

I'm willing to keep a tab in an app (It's a grocery app for a local supershop) where the user can send a message to the facebook page of that grocery shop. [here's a design of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FanKW.png).

I need it to look like [something like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNLVL.png)

[Btw My Role in this project was to Design the product from client requirements. Apparently they wanted a messaging feature in a mobile app, Implementing a chat of our own sounded unreasonable since the grocery store already had facebook to communicate with users when necessary]